# Efficient persistence strategy for many-to-many relationship

Tags: database, data-structures, set

**TL;DR: should I use an SQL JOIN table or Redis sets to store large amounts of many-to-many relationships**

I have in-memory object graph structure where I have a "many-to-many" index represented as a bidirectional mapping between ordered sets:

```
group_by_user |  user_by_group
--------------+---------------
louis: [1,2]  |   1: [louis]
john: [2,3]   |   2: [john, louis]
              |   3: [john]
```

The basic operations that I need to be able to perform are atomic "insert at" and "delete" operations on the individual sets. I also need to be able to do efficient key lookup (e.g. lookup all groups a user is a member of, or lookup all the users who are members of one group). I am looking at a 70/30 read/write use case.

My question is: what is my best bet for persisting this kind of data structure? Should I be looking at building my own optimized on-disk storage system? Otherwise, is there a particular database that would excel at storing this kind of structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you read any further: *stop being afraid of JOINs*. This is a classic case for using a genuine relational database such as Postgres.

There are a few reasons for this:

- This is what a real RDBMS is optimized for
- The database can take care of your integrity constraints as a matter of course
- This is what a real RDBMS is optimized for
- You will have to push "join" logic into your own code
- This is what a real RDBMS is optimized for
- You will have to deal with integrity concerns in your own code
- This is what a real RDBMS is optimized for
- You will wind up reinventing database features in your own code
- This is what a real RDBMS is optimized for

Yes, I am being a little silly, but because I'm trying to drive home a point.

I am beating on that drum so hard because this is a classic case that has a readily available, *extremely optimized* and *profoundly stable* tool custom designed for it.

When I say that you will wind up reinventing database features I mean that you will start having to make basic data management decisions in your own code. For example, you will have to choose when to actually write the data to disk, when to pull it, how to keep track of the highest-frequency use data and cache it in memory (and how to manage that cache), etc. Making performance assumptions into your code early can give your whole codebase cancer early on without you noticing it -- and if those assumptions prove false later changing them can require a major rewrite.

If you store the data on either end of the many-to-many relationship in one store and the many-to-many map in another store you will have to:

1. Locate the initial data on one side of the mapping
2. Extract the key(s)
3. Query for the key(s) in the many-to-many handler
4. Receive the response set(s)
5. Query whatever is relevant from your other storage based on the result
6. Build your answer for use within the system

If you structure your data within an RDBMS to begin with your code will look more like:

1. Run a pre-built query indexed over whatever your search criteria is
2. Build an answer from the response

JOINs are *a lot* less scary than doing it all yourself -- especially in a concurrent system where other things may be changing in the course of your ad hoc locate-extract-query-receive-query-build procedure (which can be managed, of course, but why manage it when an RDBMS is already designed to manage it?).

JOIN isn't even a slow operation in decent databases. I have some business applications that join 20 tables constantly over fairly large tables (several millions of rows) and it zips right through them. It is highly optimized for this sort of thing which is why I use it. Oracle does well at this (but I can't afford it), DB2 is awesome (can't afford that, either), and SQL Server has come a *long* way (can't afford the good version of that one either!). MySQL, on the other hand, was really designed with the key-value store use-case in mind and matured in the "performance above all else" world of web applications -- and so it has some problems with integrity constraints and JOINs (but has handled replication *very* well for a very long time). So not all RDBMSes are created equal, but without knowing anything else about your problem they are the kind of datastore that will serve you best.

Even slightly non-trivial data can make your code explode in complexity -- hence the popularity of database systems. They aren't (supposed to be) religions, they are tools to let you separate a generic data-handling task from your own program's logic so you don't have to reinvent the wheel every project (but we tend to anyway).

**But**

Q: When would you *not* want to do this?

A: When you are really building a *graph* and not a set of many-to-many relations.

There is other type of database designed specifically to handle that case. You need to keep in mind, though, what your actual requirements are. Is this data ephemeral? Does it have to be correct? Do you care if you lose it? Does it need to be replicated? etc. Most of the time requirements are relatively trivial and the answer is "no" to these sort of higher-flying questions -- but if you have some special *operational* needs then you may need to take them into account when making your *architectural* decision.

If you are storing things that are actually documents (instead of structured records) on the one hand, and need to track a graph of relationships among them on the other then a combination of back-ends may be a good idea. A document database + a graphing database glued together by some custom code could be the right thing.

Think carefully about which kind of situation you are *actually* facing instead of assuming you have case X because it is what you are already familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

In relational databases (e. g. SqlServer, MySql, Oracle...), the typical way of representing such data structures is with a "link table". For example:

```
users table:
userId (primary key)
userName
...

groups table:
groupId (primary key)
...

userGroups table: (this is the link table)
userId (foreign key to users table)
groupId (foreign key to groups table)
compound primary key of (userId, groupId)
```

Thus, to find all groups with users named "fred", you might write the following query:

```
SELECT g.*
FROM users u
JOIN userGroups ug ON ug.userId = u.userId
JOIN groups g ON g.groupId = ug.groupId
WHERE u.name = 'fred'
```

To achieve atomic inserts, updates, and deletes of this structure, you'll have to execute the queries that modify the various tables in transactions. ORM's such as EntityFramework (for .NET) will typically handle this for you.

Comment: Can you comment on how that would compare in terms of performance versus other database approaches, such as using Redis sets?